# Oracle SQL - Dynamic pivot

Tags: oracle

Can someone please help me on this SQL query?
I have a simple table that i need to pivot dynamically. the table consists of 3 fields as below.

```
Table
Part_no
Forecast_date
Forecast_qty
```

I would like to pivot the table on `forecast_date` so that I would see `part_no` as a row, `forecast_date` as the column heading and `forecast_qty` showing for each part/date combination.
Is this possible?

[[image: table contents]]

Comment: It is possible, but what is the benefit? And, "it is possible" but not easy; you need to write code that will generate the code for the final query (this is what's called "dynamic SQL"). Dynamic SQL is generally not a good idea. If you need this for a report, then your reporting tool (not SQL) should be able to format your data that way.

Comment: @mathguy oracle doesnt have a dynamic pivot query like MSSQL ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamic pivot in oracle sql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15491661/dynamic-pivot-in-oracle-sql)

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza - Quoting Tom Kyte (one of the real gurus in the Oracle world): *The short answer is "no"* (but see the long answers too). https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::NO::P11_QUESTION_ID:5312784100346298561