# Oracle SQL: how to merge n lines and create additional columns in result?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

Table:

```
id race
1  elf
1  troll
2  lizard
2  elf
2  human    
3  dwarf
```

I am looking for a request that output this:

```
id race1   race2   race3
1  elf     troll   
2  lizard  elf     human
3  dwarf
```

There can be n race or a given max number of races if it's more easy

Is this possible with an sql query (not pl/sql)? (oracle if special function is needed)

Comment: A SQL query has a fixed number of defined columns.  You can only do what you want with dynamic SQL (`execute immediate`).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamic pivot in oracle sql - Procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42009404/dynamic-pivot-in-oracle-sql-procedure)

Comment: @GordonLinoff ok so let's say with maximum 5 races, it could be possible ?

Comment: @KaushikNayak I am not looking for pl/sql but for a sql request. I will make it more clear in the question

Comment: If it's unknown number of columns, then pure sql solution won't be possible unless you want an XML output. With fixed columns you can

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation if you want to do this in a simple `select`:

```
select id,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then race end) as race_1,
       max(case when seqnum = 2 then race end) as race_2,
       max(case when seqnum = 3 then race end) as race_3,
       max(case when seqnum = 4 then race end) as race_4,
       max(case when seqnum = 5 then race end) as race_5
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by id order by id) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
group by id;
```