# query output changes using sql

Tags: sql, oracle

How to convert the sql output in below format for the following table?

### Table

```
Date(col 1) Name(col 2)  Value(col 3))
2018-03-05 A_SPACE       5534
2018-03-05 B_SPACE        34324
2018-03-06 A_SPACE       4645
2018-03-06 B_SPACE        435
```

### Expected format

```
Date            A_SPACE     B_SPACE     
---             ---             ---         
2018-03-05      5534            34324   
2018-03-06      4645            435
```

Comment: @Aurelien Ok updating

Comment: Search (in the documentation, on this site, or on the web generally) for 'pivot'.

Comment: @AlexPoole Yes, i think i'm looking for pivot

Answer (score 1):

If you have a *table*, the simplest way is probably conditional aggregation:

```
select date,
       sum(case when name = 'A_SPACE' then value else 0 end) as a_space,
       sum(case when name = 'B_SPACE' then value else 0 end) as b_space
from t
group by date
order by date;
```

If your table is the result of a query, then you can probably incorporate similar logic into the query.

Comment: We have more columns like a_space, b_space, c_space and so on... which can be pulled from a different query. Wondering if we can automate it with pivot instead manually writing `sum statment`

Comment: @user1595858 . . . Google "Oracle dynamic pivot".

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
SELECT * 
FROM tablename PIVOT( Max(value) FOR NAME IN('A_SPACE','B_SPACE')) 
ORDER BY dates;
```

Demo: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d97ee/23/0

If you need a dynamic pivot, refer these articles.

https://technology.amis.nl/2006/05/24/dynamic-sql-pivoting-stealing-antons-thunder/
[Dynamic pivot in oracle sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15491661/dynamic-pivot-in-oracle-sql)
[dynamic columns in oracle using sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42270966/dynamic-columns-in-oracle-using-sql)