# Employee id as column department wise

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot

I need to build a query which will give me employee id as columns. Since there can be any number of employees in a department, the number of columns is decided at runtime. The output should be as below. A,B,C,D etc. are employee id's

```
DEPT EMP1 EMP2 EMP3 EMP4 ... EMP(n)
===================================
10    A   B    C     D         E(n)
20    P   Q    R     
30    X   Y
```

Comment: Search this site for `oracle+pivot`

Answer (score 3):

you need read about pivot operator

if number of employees is fixed read this
[Pivot and Unpivot](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/sql/11g-pivot-097235.html)

if number of emp is dynamic - read this thread
[Pivot Command, can the IN clause be dynamic rather than hard-coded values?](https://community.oracle.com/thread/2183084)

see this article
[Dynamic pivot in oracle sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15491661/dynamic-pivot-in-oracle-sql)

Comment: pivot needs a aggregate function. I don't want to aggregate any column but want to show the employee id's as column