# How to display transpose of a table in SQL Developer, without knowing row values

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have searched for this. And I found that use of pivot can help, but i do not know the values that will be retrieved for the table.

[Using Oracle 11i]

Table  details:

```
    create table tr_udt_112_tmp
    (
      t_id number primary key,
      type_cd varchar(20),
      type_val varchar(80)
    );
```

Example Details (These are not exact values):

```
T_ID TYPE_CD TYPE_VAL
-- -- --
101 R2  BLA_BOX
104 L2  B2A_UTT
150 Y4  BKK_L10
122 H0  BLO_500
175 P9  BI9_999
```

For above case output should be:

```
R2 L2 Y4 H0 P9
-- -- -- -- --
BLA_BOX B2A_UTT BKK_L10 BLO_500 BI9_999
```

Please let me know, if it is even possible?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamic pivot in oracle sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15491661/dynamic-pivot-in-oracle-sql)

Comment: From the answers it seems not quite possible. Is it for 11i?