# Oracle comma seperated to rows with grouping

Tags: oracle

I have the following requirement.
    Do we have direct functions available in oracle 12c to accomplish this.

```
create table t1(input_name varchar2(500),input_values varchar2(500));
insert into t1 values('a,b,c,d,','1,2,3,4');
insert into t1 values('e,f,g,','5,6,7');
insert into t1 values('a1,b1,c1,d1,','11,12,13,14');
insert into t1 values('d,c,b,a,','100,200,300,400');
commit;

select * from t1;
INPUT_NAME                     INPUT_VALUES
------------------------------ ----------------
a,b,c,d,                       1,2,3,4
e,f,g,                         5,6,7
a1,b1,c1,d1,                   11,12,13,14
d,c,b,a,                       100,200,300,400

output:
a   b   c   d   e f g a1 b1 c1 d1
1   2   3   4   5 6 7 11 12 13 14
400 300 200 100
```

Thanks,
Rahmat Ali

Comment: You are looking for `listagg()`

Comment: Do you expect your output to be a concatenation of the strings or do you want a pivot with each input name being in a separate column?

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, Yes I need pivot for each input name.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, yes indeed, I am looking for pivot for each input name, Is there a way where I can avoid using types?

Comment: Thanks MTO, the solution was working but had perf issues, so we opted for Java transformation script in informatica.

Answer (score 1):

Yes... if you have a known set of input names. But you would be better reorganising your data so that you are not storing correlated pairs of comma-separated lists.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/5d960/10)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
create table t1(input_name,input_values) AS
SELECT 'a,b,c,d,','1,2,3,4' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'e,f,g,','5,6,7' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'a1,b1,c1,d1,','11,12,13,14' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'd,c,b,a,','100,200,300,400' FROM DUAL
/
CREATE TYPE pair IS OBJECT(
  name  VARCHAR2(20),
  value VARCHAR2(20)
)
/

CREATE TYPE pair_table IS TABLE OF PAIR
/
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT MAX( CASE name WHEN 'a' THEN value END ) AS a,
       MAX( CASE name WHEN 'b' THEN value END ) AS b,
       MAX( CASE name WHEN 'c' THEN value END ) AS c,
       MAX( CASE name WHEN 'd' THEN value END ) AS d,
       MAX( CASE name WHEN 'e' THEN value END ) AS e,
       MAX( CASE name WHEN 'f' THEN value END ) AS f,
       MAX( CASE name WHEN 'g' THEN value END ) AS g,
       MAX( CASE name WHEN 'a1' THEN value END ) AS a1,
       MAX( CASE name WHEN 'b1' THEN value END ) AS b1,
       MAX( CASE name WHEN 'c1' THEN value END ) AS c1,
       MAX( CASE name WHEN 'd1' THEN value END ) AS d1
FROM   (
  SELECT v.name,
         v.value,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY v.name ORDER BY ROWNUM ) AS rn
  FROM   t1 t
         CROSS JOIN
         TABLE(
           CAST(
             MULTISET(
               SELECT pair(
                        REGEXP_SUBSTR( t.input_name,   '([^,]+)(,|$)', 1, LEVEL, NULL, 1 ),
                        REGEXP_SUBSTR( t.input_values, '([^,]+)(,|$)', 1, LEVEL, NULL, 1 )
                      )
               FROM   DUAL
               CONNECT BY level <= REGEXP_COUNT( t.input_name, '([^,]+)(,|$)' )
             ) AS pair_table
           )
         ) v
)
GROUP BY rn
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/5d960/10/0)**:

```
|   A |   B |   C |   D |      E |      F |      G |     A1 |     B1 |     C1 |     D1 |
|-----|-----|-----|-----|--------|--------|--------|--------|--------|--------|--------|
|   1 |   2 |   3 |   4 |      5 |      6 |      7 |     11 |     12 |     13 |     14 |
| 400 | 300 | 200 | 100 | (null) | (null) | (null) | (null) | (null) | (null) | (null) |
```

You can also use a `PIVOT` statement rather than multiple `MAX( CASE ... END )` statements.

If you do not have a static set of input names then you will need to search for [dynamic pivots](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15491661/1509264).

**Update**:

> Is there a way where I can avoid using types?

You can avoid creating types and just use a built-in `VARRAY` or collection like `SYS.ODCIVARCHAR2LIST` but then you will need two lists and it becomes complicated to correlate between the two.

```
WITH input_names ( rid, idx, name ) AS (
  SELECT t.ROWID,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY t.ROWID ORDER BY ROWNUM ) AS rn,
         v.COLUMN_VALUE
  FROM   t1 t
         CROSS JOIN
         TABLE(
           CAST(
             MULTISET(
               SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR( t.input_name,   '([^,]+)(,|$)', 1, LEVEL, NULL, 1 )
               FROM   DUAL
               CONNECT BY level <= REGEXP_COUNT( t.input_name, '([^,]+)(,|$)' )
             ) AS SYS.ODCIVARCHAR2LIST
           )
         ) v
),
input_values ( rid, idx, value ) AS (
  SELECT t.ROWID,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY t.ROWID ORDER BY ROWNUM ) AS rn,
         v.COLUMN_VALUE
  FROM   t1 t
         CROSS JOIN
         TABLE(
           CAST(
             MULTISET(
               SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR( t.input_values,   '([^,]+)(,|$)', 1, LEVEL, NULL, 1 )
               FROM   DUAL
               CONNECT BY level <= REGEXP_COUNT( t.input_values, '([^,]+)(,|$)' )
             ) AS SYS.ODCIVARCHAR2LIST
           )
         ) v
),
correlated ( name, value, rn ) AS (
  SELECT n.name,
         v.value,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY n.name
                             ORDER BY ROWNUM )
  FROM   input_names n
         INNER JOIN
         input_values v
         ON ( n.rid = v.rid AND n.idx = v.idx )
)
SELECT MAX( CASE name WHEN 'a' THEN value END ) AS a,
       MAX( CASE name WHEN 'b' THEN value END ) AS b,
       MAX( CASE name WHEN 'c' THEN value END ) AS c,
       MAX( CASE name WHEN 'd' THEN value END ) AS d,
       MAX( CASE name WHEN 'e' THEN value END ) AS e,
       MAX( CASE name WHEN 'f' THEN value END ) AS f,
       MAX( CASE name WHEN 'g' THEN value END ) AS g,
       MAX( CASE name WHEN 'a1' THEN value END ) AS a1,
       MAX( CASE name WHEN 'b1' THEN value END ) AS b1,
       MAX( CASE name WHEN 'c1' THEN value END ) AS c1,
       MAX( CASE name WHEN 'd1' THEN value END ) AS d1
FROM   correlated
GROUP BY rn;
```

Comment: with kv_pair
as
(select distinct REGEXP_SUBSTR(input_name,   '([^,]+)(,|$)', 1, LEVEL, NULL, 1 ) input_name,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR(input_values, '([^,]+)(,|$)', 1, LEVEL, NULL, 1 ) input_value
from t1
CONNECT BY level <= REGEXP_COUNT( input_name, '([^,]+)(,|$)' )
)

Comment: Can I build on top this query INPUT_NAME INPUT_VALU
---------- ----------
a          400
a          1
a1         11
b          2
b          300
b1         12
c          3
c          200
c1         13
d          100
d          4
d1         14
e          5
f          6
g          7

Comment: @Rahmat Updated