# pivot in oracle gives error for sql query after in

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot

I have a table commission_new as output of commission_new table:

[image]

when I use the SQL:

```
 select * from  
    (   select employee_no,years ,subtotal from
        commission_new
    )
    pivot
    (  sum(subtotal) for years in (1999,2001,2000,2003)
        --(select distinct nvl(years,0) from commission_new)   
    )
order by employee_no;
```

I get the result

[image]

but if I use

```
(select distinct nvl(years,0) from commission_test )
```

instead of

```
(1999,2001,2000,2003)
```

I get the error:

[image]

> Error at Line: 7 Column: 6 ORA-00936: missing expression

even though the SQL `select distinct nvl(years,0) from commission_test` gives the same years as result.
What may be the reason of this?

Comment: That's not an allowed syntax : You may want dynamic Pivot instead, See this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15491661/dynamic-pivot-in-oracle-sql

Comment: There was also quite interesting solution, described here: https://technology.amis.nl/2006/05/24/dynamic-sql-pivoting-stealing-antons-thunder/