# SQL query to get following result

Tags: sql, oracle

**Table :**

```
create table stock(bDate date, packing varchar(100),  Balance number);

insert into stock values(to_date('1-JAN-2019','DD-MM-YY'),'10kg Normal Bags', 60);
insert into stock values(to_date('1-JAN-2019','DD-MM-YY'),'15kg Box', 60);
insert into stock values(to_date('1-JAN-2019','DD-MM-YY'),'Cealing Role',  60);
insert into stock values(to_date('1-JAN-2019','DD-MM-YY'),'Cello Tape', 60);

insert into stock values(to_date('2-JAN-2019','DD-MM-YY'),'10kg Normal Bags',  70);
insert into stock values(to_date('2-JAN-2019','DD-MM-YY'),'15kg Box',70);
insert into stock values(to_date('2-JAN-2019','DD-MM-YY'),'Cealing Role', 70);
insert into stock values(to_date('2-JAN-2019','DD-MM-YY'),'Cello Tape',  70);

insert into stock values(to_date('3-JAN-2019','DD-MM-YY'),'10kg Normal Bags',80);
insert into stock values(to_date('3-JAN-2019','DD-MM-YY'),'15kg Box', 80);
insert into stock values(to_date('3-JAN-2019','DD-MM-YY'),'Cealing Role', 80);
insert into stock values(to_date('3-JAN-2019','DD-MM-YY'),'Cello Tape', 80);
```

Looks like

[image]

Now I want to represent the data from this table it as follow

[image]

**I tried,**

```
SELECT * FROM
(
  SELECT * FROM stock
)
PIVOT 
(
  MAX(Balance)
  FOR bDate
  IN (to_date('1-jan-2019','DD-MM-YYYY') as "1-JAN-2019", to_date('2-jan-2019','DD-MM-YYYY') as "2-JAN-2019" , to_date('3-jan-2019','DD-MM-YYYY')  as "3-JAN-2019")
)
ORDER BY packing;
```

I got expected output. But records of future dates such as 4-JAN-2019, 5-JAN-2019 etc will be added dynamically. Then how can I manage it in above query?

**I've tried,**

```
SELECT * FROM
(
  SELECT * FROM stock
)
PIVOT 
(
  MAX(Balance)
  FOR bDate
  IN (select distinct(bDate) from stock)
)
ORDER BY packing;
```

**Error :**

```
ORA-00936: missing expression
00936. 00000 -  "missing expression"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 9 Column: 7
```

How can I achieve this result dynamically with column labels as corresponding date as shown in picture?

Comment: Oracle errors come from the Oracle database.  That is the only database tag you need.

Comment: mysql users may have alternative way to achieve the expected result, hence I tagged them too

Comment: Unfortunately, you're not going to be able to dynamically change the number of columns returned using standard SQL (or at least, you can't do this easily). The best alternative is to create a PL/SQL procedure that will dynamically return the desired number of columns.

Comment: see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15491661/dynamic-pivot-in-oracle-sql