# compare two tables and get record new and old values

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables table A(master table)- 250 columns and table b(history table)- 240 columns, 
I need to create dynamic query as i table have 250 columns. using oracle

```
suppose:  Table A(Master table)

ID  Name    City    Phone   Category 
---------------------------------------
111 ABC    Delhi    123456  Red
112 BCD    Mumbai   234987  Green
113 CGU    PUNE     987456  Black

suppose:  Table B(History table)



 ID  City   Phone   Category 
 ---------------------------------
 111 Kerala 123456  White 
 113 Jammu  577756  Black
```

I need output something like that

```
ID  changes column name Old_value   new_value
----------------------------------------------------------
111         City        Kerala      Delhi
111         Category    White       Red
113         City        Jammu       Pune 
113         Phone       987456      577756
```

but This is not dynamic i am using oracle

```
select distinct 
  hist.ID, 
  'city' as Changed_Column, 
  hist.cityas Old_Value, 
  daily.cityas New_Value
from table A dly  daily 
inner join table b hist on daily.ID= hist.ID
  and daily.city <> hist.city
```

Comment: What happens when the columns are of different types?

Comment: yes... columns are different

Answer (score 2):

Use `UNPIVOT` to convert the columns to rows in each table and then join the two:

**Oracle Setup**:

```sql
CREATE TABLE TableA ( ID, Name, City, Phone, Category ) AS
SELECT 111, 'ABC', 'Delhi',  '123456', 'Red'   FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 112, 'BCD', 'Mumbai', '234987', 'Green' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 113, 'CGU', 'PUNE',   '987456', 'Black' FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE TableB ( ID, City, Phone, Category ) AS
SELECT 111, 'Kerala', '123456', 'White' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 113, 'Jammu',  '577756', 'Black' FROM DUAL
```

**Query**:

```sql
SELECT a.id,
       a.column_name,
       a.old_value,
       b.new_value
FROM   (
         SELECT id, column_name, old_value
         FROM   TableA
         UNPIVOT ( old_value FOR column_name IN ( City, Phone, Category ) )
       ) a
       INNER JOIN
       (
         SELECT id, column_name, new_value
         FROM   TableB
         UNPIVOT ( new_value FOR column_name IN ( City, Phone, Category ) )
       ) b
       ON ( a.id = b.id AND a.column_name = b.column_name )
WHERE a.old_value <> b.new_value
```

**Output**:

> ```
>  ID | COLUMN_NAME | OLD_VALUE | NEW_VALUE
> --: | :---------- | :-------- | :--------
> 111 | CITY        | Delhi     | Kerala   
> 111 | CATEGORY    | Red       | White    
> 113 | CITY        | PUNE      | Jammu    
> 113 | PHONE       | 987456    | 577756
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=b63dafc091ab726a2915cb355ef43904)*

Comment: @MTO . . . This assumes that all the values are strings.

Comment: yes.. thanks, but i need dynamically as i have 250 columns

Comment: @GordonLinoff That is easy to fix - just convert all the columns into the same data type (i.e. a string) [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=4abdb5e3daaec7f56bf77dbad1dc9af8)

Comment: @kirtichoudhary You cannot use a [dynamic `PIVOT`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15491661/dynamic-pivot-in-oracle-sql) or `UNPIVOT` in SQL queries. You need to have a fixed set of columns - why not just list all 250 columns in the `UNPIVOT`'s `IN` list? The query will handle it.

Comment: @MT0 . . . That could change the values in the columns.  For instance, dates might lose their time component.

Comment: @GordonLinoff No, they don't need to. That's what ISO8601 formatting is for (amongst many other options): `TO_CHAR( date_value, 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS' )`

Comment: @kirtichoudhary "this is not working" is not a constructive statement. Why is it not working for you and what are the errors/issues that have occurred? The answer I've given gives the expected output for the [MRE] in your question; so if you are having trouble applying it to your full data set then you need to look at what is different from your example in the question to your actual data and debug those parts. If you want an "other way" then you're going to have to clarify what it is that you want to get an "other way".