# SQL: aggregate and condense

Tags: sql, oracle, select, sql-order-by

I could do with something I can’t figure out how to do. I have a simple query that I need to aggregate and condense. Here is the base script:

```
select t.serial, t.make, t.model, t.upgrade_date, t.software_version             
FROM table t
Order by t.serial
```

These are electrical devices that have been software upgraded (up to 3 times). The script above, of course, will provided multiple rows for the same device but with varying software versions while the make and model remain constant. I understand how to aggregate this to a single row using max to, for example, show the latest software version. However, what I need is to aggregate and have a condensed column showing EVERY software_version (in order) the device has been at.

It could look like this:

```
+------------------------------------------+ 
| Serial | Make | Model | Version_history  |
+------------------------------------------+
| A        Terra  1       1.1, 1.9, 2.1    |
+------------------------------------------+
```

Alternatively, and possibly better, it would be fine to show each software_version as a column header with ‘upgrade_date’ if the device was at that version. Actually, it would be useful to know both methods.

This could look like this:

```
+------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Serial   Make   Model   1.1           1.9           2.1            2.3 |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| A        Terra  1       01-Jan-2019   17-Jun-2019   31-Dec-2019        |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

No doubt this is really simple but I can’t for the life of me figure it out.

Comment: The first output can easily be achieved using `listagg()`

Comment: Brilliant. That was quite simple. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `LISTAGG`:

```sql
select serial,
       make,
       model,
       LISTAGG( software_version, ',' ) WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY upgrade_date )
         AS Version_history,
       LISTAGG( upgrade_date, ',' ) WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY upgrade_date )
         AS Version_dates
FROM   table
GROUP BY serial, make, model
Order by serial
```

> Alternatively, and possibly better, it would be fine to show each software_version as a column header with ‘upgrade_date’ if the device was at that version.

If you know the versions then you can do this with a `PIVOT`:

```sql
SELECT serial,
       make,
       model,
       "1.1",
       "1.9",
       "2.1",
       "2.3"
FROM   table
PIVOT ( MAX( upgrade_date ) FOR software_version IN (
  '1.1' AS "1.1",
  '1.9' AS "1.9",
  '2.1' AS "2.1",
  '2.3' AS "2.3"
) )
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=aab545e13c5fece760fa18a5f9e1db9f)

If you don't know the versions then this would be a [dynamic pivot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15491661/dynamic-pivot-in-oracle-sql) and is not a simple SQL query. You would need to use a two stage process to first generate a dynamic SQL query and then second use `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` to run the query. In general, you shouldn't use dynamic pivots and, instead, transpose rows to columns in whatever programming interface you're using to access the database (Java, Python, C#, etc.).

Comment: Thank you so much. That worked precisely how I wanted. For now there are only 3 software_vers but long term there will be many. The solution works for now and I'll brush up on dynamic pivots.

Comment: @Sid Don't use dynamic pivots in Oracle. Just use `SELECT serial, make, model, software_version, upgrade_date FROM table` and then transpose it in whatever middle tier software (JSP, PHP, Python, C#, ColdFusion, etc) to pivot rows to columns there; it will probably be a lot simpler to achieve and maintain if you do it there rather than in Oracle (which likes to have a well-defined and static set of columns).