# Oracle - Pivot table without aggregation function

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, pivot, pivot-table

I have the following table :

[image]

i've tried a pivot function that looked like this :

[image]

but it didn't worked, since there no agregation i think..

[image]

my goal is to make the table looked like this

[image]

do me a favour, thanks!

Comment: Number of columns must be finite and known in advance in PIVOT. let us know how many columns is needed in the result

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15491661/dynamic-pivot-in-oracle-sql) answer your question?

Comment: especially you can look at the dynamic solutions within the shared link.