# Oracle: transpose column to row

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot, aggregate-functions

I have the data in the following tables

```
  bins  |   pro
  -------------
    1   |   0.10
    2   |   0.05
    3   |   0.78
    4   |   0.20 
    5   |   0.82
    6   |   0.45
```

I need a query with this result:

```
   1    |   2   |   3   |   4   |   5   |   6
-------------------------------------------------
  0.10  | 0.05  |  0.78 |  0.20 |  0.82 |  0.45
```

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65055157/5841306) answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

For a fixed list of bins, you can do conditional aggregation:

```
select 
    max(case when bins = 1 then pro end) as bins1,
    max(case when bins = 2 then pro end) as bins2
    ...
    max(case when bins = 6 then pro end) as bins6
from mytable
```

Answer (score 0):

Or, using `pivot` itself:

```
SQL> with data (bins, pro) as
  2  -- sample data
  3    (select 1, 0.1  from dual union all
  4     select 2, 0.05 from dual union all
  5     select 3, 0.78 from dual union all
  6     select 4, 0.2  from dual union all
  7     select 5, 0.82 from dual union all
  8     select 6, 0.45 from dual
  9    )
 10  -- pivoting begins here
 11  select *
 12  from (select bins, pro
 13        from data
 14       )
 15  pivot
 16    (max(pro)
 17     for bins in (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
 18    )
 19  ;

    1     2     3     4     5     6
----- ----- ----- ----- ----- -----
 0.10  0.05  0.78  0.20  0.82  0.45

SQL>
```