# Oracle sql pivoting values separated by commas

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot

I have the below input

| ID | LOTYP | PROID | LOCKR |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| XXXXX | 06 | 01 | Y |
| XXXXX | 06 | 02 | X |
| XXXXX | 06 | 02 | S |
| XXXXX | 06 | 01 | R |
| XXXXX | 02 | 01 | Y |
| XXXXX | 02 | 02 | X |
| XXXXX | 02 | 02 | S |
| XXXXX | 02 | 01 | R |
| YYYYY | 06 | 01 | Y |
| YYYYY | 06 | 02 | X |
| YYYYY | 06 | 02 | S |
| YYYYY | 06 | 01 | R |
| YYYYY | 02 | 01 | Y |
| YYYYY | 02 | 02 | X |
| YYYYY | 02 | 02 | S |
| YYYYY | 02 | 01 | R |

I would like the below output

| ID | 0201 | 0202 | 0601 | 0602 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| XXXXX | R, Y | S, X | R, Y | S, X |
| YYYYY | R, Y | S, X | R, Y | S, X |

I can pivot and listagg separately but I'm struggling to combine them to produce the desired output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pivot the grouped results for `id` and concatenated (`lotyp||proid`) columns such as

```
SELECT *
  FROM
  (
    SELECT id,lotyp||proid As title,
           LISTAGG(lockr,',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY lotyp||proid) AS value
      FROM t
     GROUP BY id,lotyp||proid )
 PIVOT (
         MAX(value) FOR title IN ('0201' AS "0201",
                                  '0202' AS "0202",
                                  '0601' AS "0601",
                                  '0602' AS "0602"))   
 ORDER BY id;
```

| ID | 0201 | 0202 | 0601 | 0602 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| XXXXX | R,Y | S,X | R,Y | S,X |
| YYYYY | R,Y | S,X | R,Y | S,X |

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=05ce63363cb9e8e17c56f426e43875c6)</kbd>

Comment: Thanks! I hadn't thought of that way. Now I don't know how to, if, let's say, the result is R, R, R, R, Y, putting 4R, Y. But I'll ask this on a separate question.

Comment: you're welcome @JaviTorre . You can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65055157/5841306) out for dynamic option.

Answer (score 1):

I just find conditional aggregation so much simpler than `pivot`:

```
SELECT id,
       LISTAGG(CASE WHEN lotyp = '02' AND proid = '01' THEN lockr END, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY lockr) as "0201",
       LISTAGG(CASE WHEN lotyp = '02' AND proid = '02' THEN lockr END, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY lockr) as "0201",
       LISTAGG(CASE WHEN lotyp = '06' AND proid = '01' THEN lockr END, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY lockr) as "0601",
       LISTAGG(CASE WHEN lotyp = '02' AND proid = '01' THEN lockr END, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY lockr) as "0601"
FROM t
GROUP BY id ;
```

No subqueries.  Just logic that clearly does what you are trying to do.

Comment: Thanks! This is also a good solution, although not escalable for many combinations lotyp/proid.

Comment: @JaviTorre . . . I'm not sure what you mean by scalable.  Conditional aggregation usually runs as fast as or faster than `pivot`.  Plus, this avoids the aggregation in the subquery which should make it hands-down faster.