# ORACLE SQL: How to group and count data by column?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables:

**Table A:**

| ID | CODE | time-stamp |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Aid_z | code_z | 2020-07-21 |
| ... | ... | ... |
| Aid_1 | code_1 | 2020-11-30 |
| Aid_2 | code_2 | 2020-11-30 |
| Aid_3 | code_2 | 2020-11-30 |
| Aid_4 | code_1 | 2020-11-30 |
| Aid_5 | code_3 | 2020-11-30 |
| ... | ... | ... |
| Aid_n | code_x | 2021-04-06 |

ID is unique, there is **67** distinct CODEs.

**Table B:**

| ID | ID_A | status | value | time-stamp |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Bid_z | Aid_z | z | ... | 2020-07-21 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| Bid_1 | Aid_1 | 1 | 101.1 | 2020-11-30 |
| Bid_2 | Aid_2 | 0 | 87.6 | 2020-11-30 |
| Bid_3 | Aid_3 | 0 | 76.2 | 2020-11-30 |
| Bid_4 | Aid_4 | 1 | 106.2 | 2020-11-30 |
| Bid_5 | Aid_5 | 2 | 124.6 | 2020-11-30 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| Bid_n | Aid_n | x | ... | 2021-04-06 |

ID is unique, ID_A is the same as ID from Table A.

What I need to do is:

1. Count how much of all records are each day
2. Count amount of each distinct CODEs
3. Present them as a columns and each row should be representing one day
4. Only for status "0" or "1" from Table B
5. Only for records between 2020-11-30 and 2021-02-06

In the end reasult should looks like:

| date (per day) | sum_of_this_day | code_1 | code_2 | code_2 | ... | code_z |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-11-30 | 35 | 5 | 0 | 10 | ... | x |
| 2020-11-31 | 60 | 6 | 5 | 12 | ... | x |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 2021-02-06 | 47 | 6 | 5 | 12 | ... | x |

Comment: And what did you try so far?

Comment: I alredy count with WHERE-clause taking into consideration date range and status. But I have problem to put everything in one query that give me the reasult as stated in my post - each day separately nad each column representing different CODE. Is it even possible to make one like that?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15491661/dynamic-pivot-in-oracle-sql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried this solution, let me know if this helps.
I filtered rows on your conditions
Only for status "0" or "1" from Table B
Only for records between 2020-11-30 and 2021-02-06
then I have a table with those codes which satisfy your condition and I used ``pivot``` to count distinct codes for each day and in a separate table, I counted the total codes of that day and joined these two tables to get the final output
distinct_day, total_codes, code1_count, code2_count,...codez_count

```
With filtered_table as (select A.time_stamp time_stamp , A.code code from A inner join B
                        on(A.id = B.id_a)
                        where B.status in (0, 1)
                        and A.time_stamp between to_date('2020-11-30','yyyy-mm-dd')  and to_date('2021-02-06','yyyy-mm-dd')),
     pivot_table as (select * from ( select time_stamp t1, code from filtered_table)
                    pivot ( count(code) for code  in ( 'code_1', 'code_2', 'code_3', 'code_z') )),
     every_day_cnt as ( SELECT time_stamp, count(code) cnt from filtered_table GROUP BY time_stamp)
SELECT A.*, B.cnt from pivot_table  A inner join every_day_cnt B on (A.t1 = b.time_stamp);
```

Comment: Those dots between code values are not a working syntax.

Comment: yes, and it means you have to put your code_1, code_2 till your hypothetical code_z in order to get an aggregation of all code present in the table.