# How get all date from date range in one row - oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

How get all date from date range?

eg.  01/01/2021  to  03/01/2021

need result as one row:

```
col1        col2        col3
----------------------------------
01/01/2021  02/01/2021  03/01/2021
```

Comment: Read this https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/database/sql-11g-pivot.html

Answer (score 2):

> need result as one row:

You cannot easily do this as Oracle (and SQL, in general) requires a fixed, known set of columns to be able to execute the query.

---

If you want to generate the values as rows then that is easy and you can use a hierarchical query:

```sql
SELECT DATE '2021-01-01' + LEVEL - 1 AS value
FROM   DUAL
CONNECT BY DATE '2021-01-01' + LEVEL - 1 <= DATE '2021-01-03';
```

Or a recursive sub-query factoring clause:

```sql
WITH date_ranges ( start_date, end_date ) AS (
  SELECT DATE '2021-01-01', DATE '2021-01-03' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL
  SELECT start_date + 1, end_date FROM date_ranges WHERE start_date + 1 <= end_date
)
SELECT start_date AS value
FROM   date_ranges
```

The ideal solution to your problem of generating the values as columns would then be to transpose the rows to columns in whatever 3rd-party application you are using to access the database (PHP, C#, Java, Python, etc.) and do **NOT** try to pivot it in SQL if you have a dynamic number of columns.

Now, if you have a fixed set of columns then it is possible. For example, if you always have 3 dates:

```
WITH date_range ( start_date ) AS (
  SELECT DATE '2021-01-01' FROM DUAL
)
SELECT start_date AS col1,
       start_date + 1 AS col2,
       start_date + 2 AS col3
FROM   date_range;
```

If you want to try pivoting to a dynamic number of columns then you want a [dynamic pivot](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15491661/1509264) and will need to use one of the solutions in the linked answer (but don't, do it in the 3rd-party application instead).

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=8c8199d814ba61430eb124afbd73f68b)*

Comment: Tnx for help, I thought there was some simple slution for my problem. My date range is always different and need dynamic solution.