# How to rotate or pivot a table in sql?

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, pivot

How can I use rotate/pivot my table in sql?

my table looks like this:

| INTEGRATION | STATUS |
| --- | --- |
| INT 1 | completed |
| INT 2 | FAILED |
| INT 3 | Aborted |

I want this:

| Completed | Failed | Aborted |
| --- | --- | --- |
| INT 1 | INT 2 | INT 3 |

Comment: Is possible values list for `status` column fixed and unchangeable?

Comment: Have you tried this ? https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/pivot.php

Comment: Yes values are fixed..data is dynamic in the sense new Integrations get added everyday.

Comment: @RuiCosta...this is the o/p:           INT     Completed Failed Aborted
                                                    INT 1     completed                                                                   
                                                    INT 2                         failed                                        
                                                    INT 3                                            aborted

Answer (score 0):

for example:

```
with 
datum (INTEGRATION, STATUS)
as (
select 'INT 1','completed' from dual union all
select 'INT 2','FAILED' from dual union all
select 'INT 3','Aborted' from dual
)
select * from datum
pivot 
(
max(integration)
for status in ('completed' as "Completed",'FAILED' as "Failed",'Aborted' as "Aborted")
) ;
```

[image]

links:
[pivot/unpivot](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/database/sql-11g-pivot.html)

[How to Convert Rows to Columns](https://blogs.oracle.com/sql/how-to-convert-rows-to-columns-and-back-again-with-sql-aka-pivot-and-unpivot)

[pivoting example](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/dwhsg/sql-analysis-reporting-data-warehouses.html#GUID-84C81897-0484-4F40-938B-D1D7F5EA4D97)

Comment: But my data is dynamic...there arent just these 3 Int's.

Comment: 1)   example:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15491661/dynamic-pivot-in-oracle-sql

2) https://technology.amis.nl/oracle/dynamic-sql-pivoting-stealing-antons-thunder/