# convert lines into single row

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot

I have data like this

```
Col1 Col 2
100    1
100    2
100    3
100    4
```

need output like this

```
Col1 col2 col3 col4 col5 


100   1    2    3    4
```

need to define as new col names and populate values into these fields.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15491661/dynamic-pivot-in-oracles-sql

Comment: If the source values were 6,5,4,3 instead, what should the results be?

Comment: yes Col2 values are dynamic is there any solution to define dynamically ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is 1 more way, called Conditional aggregation to achieve the same result -

```
SELECT Col1,
       MAX(CASE WHEN Col2 = 1 THEN Col2 END) Col2,
       MAX(CASE WHEN Col2 = 2 THEN Col2 END) Col3,
       MAX(CASE WHEN Col2 = 3 THEN Col2 END) Col4,
       MAX(CASE WHEN Col2 = 4 THEN Col2 END) Col5
  FROM table_name
 GROUP BY Col1;
```

If you have 15 values, You have to pass them manually in both the queries and your result will always have 15 columns. If you want to have them dynamically transformed, refer the answer in original comment.

Comment: This looks much simple . let me put the question correctly col2 values are dynamic as we don't what we going have. but what ever in col 2 needs to spread across 1 to 15 with possible values if not null to populate

Comment: Ankit, can you please let me know how can we consider dynamical values 1 to 15. Some time we may have on1 or 2 values and rest all should populate as null in that case. if we have 15 values then populate all 15 values.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a fixed maximum number of input rows/output columns you can use:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   table_name
PIVOT (
  MAX(Col2)
  FOR Col2 IN (1 AS col2, 2 AS col3, 3 AS col4, 4 AS col5)
)
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (Col1, Col2) AS
SELECT 100, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 100, 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 100, 3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 100, 4 FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | COL1 | COL2 | COL3 | COL4 | COL5 |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 100 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |

---

If you can have a maximum of 15 rows then:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   (
  SELECT t.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Col1 ORDER BY Col2) AS rn
  FROM   table_name t
)
PIVOT (
  MAX(Col2)
  FOR rn IN (
    1 AS col2,
    2 AS col3,
    3 AS col4,
    4 AS col5,
    5 AS col6,
    6 AS col7,
    7 AS col8,
    8 AS col9,
    9 AS col10,
    10 AS col11,
    11 AS col12,
    12 AS col13,
    13 AS col14,
    14 AS col15,
    15 AS col16
  )
)
```

or:

```sql
SELECT Col1,
       MAX(CASE rn WHEN 1 THEN Col2 END) AS Col2,
       MAX(CASE rn WHEN 2 THEN Col2 END) AS Col3,
       MAX(CASE rn WHEN 3 THEN Col2 END) AS Col4,
       MAX(CASE rn WHEN 4 THEN Col2 END) AS Col5,
       MAX(CASE rn WHEN 5 THEN Col2 END) AS Col6,
       MAX(CASE rn WHEN 6 THEN Col2 END) AS Col7,
       MAX(CASE rn WHEN 7 THEN Col2 END) AS Col8,
       MAX(CASE rn WHEN 8 THEN Col2 END) AS Col9,
       MAX(CASE rn WHEN 9 THEN Col2 END) AS Col10,
       MAX(CASE rn WHEN 10 THEN Col2 END) AS Col11,
       MAX(CASE rn WHEN 11 THEN Col2 END) AS Col12,
       MAX(CASE rn WHEN 12 THEN Col2 END) AS Col13,
       MAX(CASE rn WHEN 13 THEN Col2 END) AS Col14,
       MAX(CASE rn WHEN 14 THEN Col2 END) AS Col15,
       MAX(CASE rn WHEN 15 THEN Col2 END) AS Col16
FROM   (
  SELECT t.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Col1 ORDER BY Col2) AS rn
  FROM   table_name t
)
GROUP BY Col1
```

Which both output:

> | COL1 | COL2 | COL3 | COL4 | COL5 | COL6 | COL7 | COL8 | COL9 | COL10 | COL11 | COL12 | COL13 | COL14 | COL15 | COL16 |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 100 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | *NULL* | *NULL* | *NULL* | *NULL* | *NULL* | *NULL* | *NULL* | *NULL* | *NULL* | *NULL* | *NULL* |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=40ceeb8b006c45916c3e8c7320b4eef6)*

Comment: Doesn't this just act as a boolean flag system, for whether the values 1, 2, 3, or 4 appear in the source table? For example, I'd have thought the op would still want 6 to appear in the results here? https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=fb69f5e0dc3ace59bf38dad91ad4a98c (I concede I may be missing something, and that the op is extremely vague, I'm just a bit confused as to how useful this would likely be?)

Comment: values in col2 varies ...Col1 is the key value and it will have many values in col2  (up to 15)  so i need to pivot based on the key from multiple rows to single row . can you please help me with this

Comment: then you need [dynamic-pivot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/oracle%2bdynamic-pivot?tab=Active) @jay

Comment: @jay Updated for up to 15 values. SQL (all dialects and not just Oracle) require a fixed, known number of columns to output so it is impossible to generate a dynamic number of columns with (pure) SQL and you will have to always generate the maximum number of columns.

Comment: Yes it is fixed to 15 colums but few col populate with values and few may not .. how can pivot cols dynamically