# Select only one column using case or pivot in PLSQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, pivot, case

I have a table or data like this

[image]

This data has a same invoice number, so I want to show table only one column using case or pivot. The result that I want is like this

[image]

Can you help me about this ?

Comment: Does [Dynamic Pivot in Oracle's SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15491661/dynamic-pivot-in-oracles-sql) answer your question?

Answer (score 2):

Using CASE expressions:

```sql
WITH
    tbl AS    -- Sample Data
        (
            Select 'WSIV/H/02/22/00122' "NO_INVOICE", To_Date('04.08-2022', 'dd.mm.yyyy') "PAID_DATE", 50000 "AMOUNT_APPLY" From Dual Union All
            Select 'WSIV/H/02/22/00122' "NO_INVOICE", To_Date('06.08-2022', 'dd.mm.yyyy') "PAID_DATE", 60000 "AMOUNT_APPLY" From Dual Union All
            Select 'WSIV/H/02/22/00122' "NO_INVOICE", To_Date('07.08-2022', 'dd.mm.yyyy') "PAID_DATE", 70000 "AMOUNT_APPLY" From Dual 
        )
SELECT
    NO_INVOICE,
    Max(PAID_DATE_1) "PAID_DATE_1", Max(AMOUNT_APPLY_1) "AMOUNT_APPLY_1",
    Max(PAID_DATE_2) "PAID_DATE_2", Max(AMOUNT_APPLY_2) "AMOUNT_APPLY_2",
    Max(PAID_DATE_3) "PAID_DATE_3", Max(AMOUNT_APPLY_3) "AMOUNT_APPLY_3",
    Max(PAID_DATE_4) "PAID_DATE_4", Max(AMOUNT_APPLY_4) "AMOUNT_APPLY_4",
    Nvl(Max(AMOUNT_APPLY_1), 0) + Nvl(Max(AMOUNT_APPLY_2), 0) + Nvl(Max(AMOUNT_APPLY_3), 0) + Nvl(Max(AMOUNT_APPLY_4), 0) "TOTAL"
FROM
    ( 
        Select
            NO_INVOICE,
            CASE WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER(Partition By NO_INVOICE Order By PAID_DATE) = 1 THEN PAID_DATE END "PAID_DATE_1", 
            CASE WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER(Partition By NO_INVOICE Order By PAID_DATE) = 2 THEN PAID_DATE END "PAID_DATE_2",
            CASE WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER(Partition By NO_INVOICE Order By PAID_DATE) = 3 THEN PAID_DATE END "PAID_DATE_3",
            CASE WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER(Partition By NO_INVOICE Order By PAID_DATE) = 4 THEN PAID_DATE END "PAID_DATE_4",
            CASE WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER(Partition By NO_INVOICE Order By PAID_DATE) = 1 THEN AMOUNT_APPLY END "AMOUNT_APPLY_1", 
            CASE WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER(Partition By NO_INVOICE Order By PAID_DATE) = 2 THEN AMOUNT_APPLY END "AMOUNT_APPLY_2",
            CASE WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER(Partition By NO_INVOICE Order By PAID_DATE) = 3 THEN AMOUNT_APPLY END "AMOUNT_APPLY_3",
            CASE WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER(Partition By NO_INVOICE Order By PAID_DATE) = 4 THEN AMOUNT_APPLY END "AMOUNT_APPLY_4"
        From
            tbl
    )
GROUP BY NO_INVOICE
ORDER BY NO_INVOICE
```

Result:

| NO_INVOICE | PAID_DATE_1 | AMOUNT_APPLY_1 | PAID_DATE_2 | AMOUNT_APPLY_2 | PAID_DATE_3 | AMOUNT_APPLY_3 | PAID_DATE_4 | AMOUNT_APPLY_4 | TOTAL |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| WSIV/H/02/22/00122 | 04-AUG-22 | 50000 | 06-AUG-22 | 60000 | 07-AUG-22 | 70000 |  |  | 180000 |

Comment: You need to wrap NVL(?,0) round your Max expressions in the "TOTAL" column, otherwise the total could be NULL. See your result.

Comment: @Unoembre Thank's. Just did it...

Answer (score 1):

Using `PIVOT` clause

```sql
WITH
  tbl AS    -- Sample Data
    (
      SELECT 'WSIV/H/02/22/00122' no_invoice, DATE '2022-08-04' paid_date, 50000 amount_apply FROM DUAL UNION ALL
      SELECT 'WSIV/H/02/22/00122' no_invoice, DATE '2022-08-06' paid_date, 60000 amount_apply FROM DUAL UNION ALL
      SELECT 'WSIV/H/02/22/00122' no_invoice, DATE '2022-08-07' paid_date, 70000 amount_apply FROM DUAL 
    )
SELECT
  no_invoice,
  "1_PAID_DATE" paid_date_1, "1_AMOUNT_APPLY" amount_apply_1,
  "2_PAID_DATE" paid_date_2, "2_AMOUNT_APPLY" amount_apply_2,
  "3_PAID_DATE" paid_date_3, "3_AMOUNT_APPLY" amount_apply_3,
  "4_PAID_DATE" paid_date_4, "4_AMOUNT_APPLY" amount_apply_4,
  NVL("1_AMOUNT_APPLY",0)+NVL("2_AMOUNT_APPLY",0)+NVL("3_AMOUNT_APPLY",0)+NVL("4_AMOUNT_APPLY",0)+NVL("5_AMOUNT_APPLY",0) total
FROM 
  ( SELECT 
      no_invoice, paid_date, amount_apply,
      LEAST(5, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY NO_INVOICE ORDER BY paid_date)) bucket
    FROM tbl
  )
PIVOT
  ( ANY_VALUE(paid_date) paid_date, ANY_VALUE(amount_apply) amount_apply
    FOR bucket IN (1,2,3,4,5)
  )
```

Bucket 5 is used to trap all amount_apply's beyond the first 4 dates so they may be included in the total even though those amounts will not be shown in the columns (a catch all).

In Oracles prior to 19c use `MAX` rather than `ANY_VALUE`.

If you want the paid_date's to be aggregated so that all payments for an no_invoice on the same date appear just in one column, then change `ROW_NUMBER` to `DENSE_RANK` and `ANY_VALUE(amount_apply)` to `SUM(amount_apply)`.

Result is as per OP. Thanks to @d-r for Sample Data.