# Pivot-traspose a table PL SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql, pivot

I have this table:

[image]

and I would like to have this output:

[image]

Could be possible? the problem is that I don't know how many values have the table.

Thank you very much.

Comment: I think [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65055157/5841306) will help you

Comment: In easy way you can't. 
Using dynamic SQL you could but this is not easy and check your user may have privillages to create any type before start.