# How to transform a single column with multiple rows into a single row with multiple columns using Oracle 11G?

Tags: oracle11g, pivot

I have a key/value table that represents multiple values in a single type of transaction, e.g:

| tran_type | description | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | phone | +1-999 |
| 1 | amount | 189.23 |

the thing is that a transaction type can have any number of key/value rows, and I need to display a dataset like this:

| tran_type | key | key2 | key n.. |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | +1-999 | 189.23 | hello |

I was trying to use the pivot funcionality but I got nothing so far...

any help will be appreciated in this regard

Comment: That's *dynamic pivoting*; have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15491661/dynamic-pivot-in-oracles-sql