# Dynamic Pivot in Oracle - This Errors

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, pivot

SELECT * FROM(SELECT A,DATE,COUNT(B) FROM TABLE
GROUP BY A,DATE)
PIVOT XML(SUM(B) FOR DATE IN (&x))

Where the input for x is: (list this week's Sunday with the following 4 Sundays)

select listagg(''''|| dt || '''AS'|| dt,',')
within group (order by dt) from (
Select * from  (select trunc(sysdate, 'DAY')-1 + level dt from dual connect by level <= (sysdate+30- sysdate))
where  to_char (dt,'fmday') = 'sunday');

When I perform this it errors on ORA-01858 a non-numeric character was found where a numeric character was expected etc.

Expecting to execute query

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dynamic Pivot in Oracle's SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15491661/dynamic-pivot-in-oracles-sql)

Comment: Oracle does not support dynamic pivots. Additionally, substitution variables act as if you have used a find-replace so your query would be `SELECT * FROM(SELECT A,DATE,COUNT(B) FROM TABLE GROUP BY A,DATE) PIVOT XML(SUM(B) FOR DATE IN (select listagg(''''|| dt || '''AS'|| dt,',') within group (order by dt) from ( Select * from (select trunc(sysdate, 'DAY')-1 + level dt from dual connect by level <= (sysdate+30- sysdate)) where to_char (dt,'fmday') = 'sunday')))` which is not supported syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Your code appears to be trying to do a dynamic pivot an count the `B` values that appear on each Sunday within the current day and the next 29 days.

You do not need a dynamic pivot. Just filter the table to get the Sundays before you pivot and then pivot based on how many Sundays ahead the date is (which in the next 30 days will always be have either 4 or 5 Sundays).

You also so not need to use any language-specific code as you can use `TRUNC(date_value, 'IW')` to find the start of the ISO-week (which is always midnight on Monday) and then Sundays are 1 day before the start of the ISO-week.

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   (
  SELECT A,
         (TRUNC("DATE") - (TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'IW') - 1)) / 7 AS weeknum,
         b
  FROM   "TABLE"
  WHERE  TRUNC("DATE") - TRUNC("DATE", 'IW') = 6 -- Sundays
  AND    "DATE" >= TRUNC(SYSDATE)
  AND    "DATE" <  TRUNC(SYSDATE) + 30
) PIVOT (
  COUNT(B)
  FOR weeknum IN (
    1 AS week1,
    2 AS week2,
    3 AS week3,
    4 AS week4,
    5 AS week5
  )
)
```

*Note: `TABLE` and `DATE` are reserved words and cannot be used as unquoted identifiers. Best practice would be to name your table and column by a more descriptive name but if you have to use `TABLE` and `DATE` (please don't) then you will need to use quoted identifiers (and the correct case) everywhere they are used.*

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE "TABLE" (a, "DATE", B) AS
SELECT 1, TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'IW') - 1 + 7*LEVEL, 1 FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 5;
```

Which generates the values:

| A | DATE | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-10-01 00:00:00 (SUN) | 1 |
| 1 | 2023-10-08 00:00:00 (SUN) | 1 |
| 1 | 2023-10-15 00:00:00 (SUN) | 1 |
| 1 | 2023-10-22 00:00:00 (SUN) | 1 |
| 1 | 2023-10-29 00:00:00 (SUN) | 1 |

Then the output of the `PIVOT` is:

| A | WEEK1 | WEEK2 | WEEK3 | WEEK4 | WEEK5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/iHURSwxC)