# Convert row data to column header

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to convert the following data that has dates in to column headers, using pl/sql.  I am thinking that pivot can be used but struggling to get this to work.

[image]

Desired output as follows:
[image]

Any help gratefully received.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dynamic Pivot in Oracle's SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15491661/dynamic-pivot-in-oracles-sql)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `PIVOT` and enumerate the values and use quoted identifiers to generate the column identifiers:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   table_name t
PIVOT (
  MAX(rn) FOR dt IN (
    DATE '2024-01-01' AS "01/01/2024",
    DATE '2024-01-08' AS "08/01/2024",
    DATE '2024-01-15' AS "15/01/2024",
    DATE '2024-01-22' AS "22/01/2024",
    DATE '2024-01-29' AS "29/01/2024",
    DATE '2024-02-05' AS "05/02/2024",
    DATE '2024-02-12' AS "12/02/2024"
  )
)
```

or, using conditional aggregation:

```sql
SELECT MAX(CASE dt WHEN DATE '2024-01-01' THEN rn END) AS "01/01/2024",
       MAX(CASE dt WHEN DATE '2024-01-08' THEN rn END) AS "08/01/2024",
       MAX(CASE dt WHEN DATE '2024-01-15' THEN rn END) AS "15/01/2024",
       MAX(CASE dt WHEN DATE '2024-01-22' THEN rn END) AS "22/01/2024",
       MAX(CASE dt WHEN DATE '2024-01-29' THEN rn END) AS "29/01/2024",
       MAX(CASE dt WHEN DATE '2024-02-05' THEN rn END) AS "05/02/2024",
       MAX(CASE dt WHEN DATE '2024-02-12' THEN rn END) AS "12/02/2024"
FROM   table_name
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (dt, rn) AS
SELECT DATE '2024-01-01', 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2024-01-08', 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2024-01-15', 3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2024-01-22', 4 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2024-01-29', 5 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2024-02-05', 6 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2024-02-12', 7 FROM DUAL;
```

Both output:

| 01/01/2024 | 08/01/2024 | 15/01/2024 | 22/01/2024 | 29/01/2024 | 05/02/2024 | 12/02/2024 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/WKiL3QvT)

Comment: Hello @MT0,  Thanks for your response.  The dates are generated by some code which I have put below, is there a way to dynamically build up the column headers ? (so no hard coding). 
)

Comment: With rws As (
 select Case When '&No_Of_Weeks' Is Null Then trunc(add_months(sysdate, -11),'mm')
         When '&No_Of_Weeks' Is not Null Then To_Date('&Period_ending_date','DD/MM/YYYY') - ('&No_Of_Weeks'*7) End
+ level dt
  from   dual
  connect by level <= (
    Nvl(To_Date('&Period_ending_date','DD/MM/YYYY'), last_day(trunc(sysdate)) )
    - 
    Case When '&No_Of_Weeks' Is Null Then trunc(add_months(sysdate, -11),'mm')
         When '&No_Of_Weeks' Is not Null Then To_Date('&Period_ending_date','DD/MM/YYYY') - ('&No_Of_Weeks'*7) End
  )
),

Comment: Rowsnum As (
  select dt, row_number() Over( Order by dt) rn
  from   rws
  where  to_char ( dt, 'fmday', 'nls_date_language = English'  ) = 'monday'
)

Comment: @Jannette No, SQL (not just Oracle) requires a fixed, known set of columns for a query. You either need to build a query through string concatenation and then dynamically execute that query or else (and better) return the values a rows (not columns) and then if you want to pivot it do it in whatever third-party languages (i.e. Java, C#, PHP, Python, etc) that you are using to query the database.