# Oracle SQL: How to display data from same table in multiple column based on the condition

Tags: sql, oracle

I have following  table

My_Table

```
Columns = Id , parent_id , System,  error, date_time
```

Here this is how data is :

```
Id = 1, parent_id = 1, System = null , error = null, date_time= sysdate , is_subsystem= N

Id = 2, parent_id = 1, System = A , error = null, date_time= sysdate , is_subsystem= Y  

Id = 3, parent_id = 1, System = B , error = null, date_time= sysdate , is_subsystem= Y

Id = 4, parent_id = 1, System = C , error = null, date_time= sysdate , is_subsystem= Y

Id = 5, parent_id = 1, System = D , error = null, date_time= sysdate , is_subsystem= Y
```

So, the final result I need is, If I pass ID = 1, then it should bring all the child data that has parent_id matching.

E.G.

| id | System_of_Child | System_of_Child |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | B |

here is my SQL

```sql
select T1.id, T2.system as System_of_Child  from MY_Table T1
Left join MY_Table T2 on T2.id = T1.paren_id
where Id = 1.
```

Here my result shows like

| id | System_of_Child |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | A |

The question is here: is there any way I can get all my Systems in a single row if it exists? above is just an example, in table i have few more column which i need to display based on the parent_id.

Comment: You say Oracle SQL in the title, but you tag [tag:mysql]. Please use only the tags for the brand of database you are using. You won't get better answers by over-tagging.

Answer (score 0):

In SQL (not just Oracle) a `SELECT` statement outputs a fixed, known number of columns. You **CANNOT** have a static query that generates a dynamic number of columns.

Given the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (id, parent_id, system, date_time, is_subsystem) AS
  SELECT 1, 1, NULL, SYSDATE, 'N' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 1, 'A',  SYSDATE, 'Y' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, 1, 'B',  SYSDATE, 'Y' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 4, 1, 'C',  SYSDATE, 'Y' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 5, 1, 'D',  SYSDATE, 'Y' FROM DUAL;
```

What you need to do is either:

1. Output rows instead of columns

   ```sql
   SELECT parent_id AS id,
          system
   FROM   table_name t
   WHERE  parent_id = 1
   AND    parent_id != id;
   ```

   Which outputs:

   | ID | SYSTEM |
   | --- | --- |
   | 1 | A |
   | 1 | B |
   | 1 | C |
   | 1 | D |
2. Aggregate the values into a single delimited column:

   ```sql
   SELECT parent_id AS id,
          LISTAGG(system, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY system) AS systems
   FROM   table_name t
   WHERE  parent_id = 1
   AND    parent_id != id
   GROUP BY parent_id;
   ```

   Which outputs:

   | ID | SYSTEMS |
   | --- | --- |
   | 1 | A,B,C,D |
3. If you really want a dynamic number of columns then output the values as rows (Option 1) and then pivot the values from rows-to-columns in whatever third-party application you are using to access the database (i.e. Python, Java, C#, PHP, etc.).
4. If you have a maximum fixed number of columns then you can pivot based on that maximum:

   ```sql
   SELECT *
   FROM   (
     SELECT parent_id AS id,
            system,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY parent_id ORDER BY system) AS rn
     FROM   table_name t
     WHERE  parent_id = 1
     AND    parent_id != id
   )
   PIVOT (
     MAX(system) FOR rn IN (
       1 AS system1,
       2 AS system2,
       3 AS system3,
       4 AS system4,
       5 AS system5
     )
   );
   ```

   Which outputs:

   | ID | SYSTEM1 | SYSTEM2 | SYSTEM3 | SYSTEM4 | SYSTEM5 |
   | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
   | 1 | A | B | C | D | *null* |
5. If you really want a dynamic number of columns and you aren't using a third-party application then you will need to generate a [dynamic SQL statement](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15491661/1509264) that calculates the number of columns you will require and then generates a static SQL statement to pivot the columns based on that.

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/6wD1hwgC)

Answer (score -1):

To display data from the same table in multiple columns based on a condition, you can use SQL's conditional logic and the `CASE` statement. Here's a basic example:

Let's say you have a table called `employees` with columns `employee_id`, `employee_name`, `department`, and `salary`. You want to display employees in two columns based on whether they belong to the "Sales" department or the "Marketing" department.

You can achieve this with a query like this:

```sql
SELECT 
    employee_id,
    employee_name,
    CASE 
        WHEN department = 'Sales' THEN salary 
        ELSE NULL 
    END AS sales_salary,
    CASE 
        WHEN department = 'Marketing' THEN salary 
        ELSE NULL 
    END AS marketing_salary
FROM 
    employees;
```

This query selects the `employee_id` and `employee_name` as they are, and then uses `CASE` statements to conditionally select the `salary` into different columns based on the department. If the employee belongs to the Sales department, their salary will be displayed in the `sales_salary` column, and if they belong to the Marketing department, their salary will be displayed in the `marketing_salary` column. If the employee doesn't belong to either department, `NULL` is displayed.

You can adjust the condition and column names according to your specific requirements and table structure.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).