Oracle Table transpose
Below is my table
CREATE TABLE "TABLE1" 
   (    "REG" VARCHAR2(20 BYTE), 
    "SB" VARCHAR2(20 BYTE), 
    "VKYC" VARCHAR2(20 BYTE)
   ) ;

Insert into TABLE1 (REG,SB,VKYC) values ('1','2','3');
Insert into TABLE1 (REG,SB,VKYC) values ('1A','3','6');
Insert into TABLE1 (REG,SB,VKYC) values ('2','4','7');
Insert into TABLE1 (REG,SB,VKYC) values ('3','5','8');
Insert into TABLE1 (REG,SB,VKYC) values ('4','6','9');
Insert into TABLE1 (REG,SB,VKYC) values ('5','7','0');

I want result like transpose:














Reg
1
1A
2
3
4
5


Sb
2
3
4
5
6
7


Vkyc
3
6
7
8
9
0




If you have a dynamic number of rows that you want to pivot to columns then this is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15491661/dynamic-pivot-in-oracles-sql

This is better done in whatever third-party language (Java, C#, PHP, Python, etc.) you are using to connect to the database as transposing data is something for displaying data and is not easy when querying data.

However, if you have a fixed number of rows that you want to output as columns then you can UNPIVOT and PIVOT to transpose:
SELECT *
FROM   ( SELECT reg, sb, vkyc,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ROWNUM) AS rn
         FROM   table1 )
       UNPIVOT(value FOR type IN (reg, sb, vkyc))
       PIVOT(MAX(value) FOR rn IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6));

Which, for the sample data, outputs:



TYPE
1
2
3
4
5
6




REG
1
1A
2
3
4
5


SB
2
3
4
5
6
7


VKYC
3
6
7
8
9
0



fiddle

Thank you. if possible, can you provide microsoft sql server query for the same requirement

@BalaS I cannot, you would do better asking a new question tagged with [sql-server].

Okay. Thank you
